# How to let the values automatically change themselves?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[3];
    Arrays.fill(arr, 1);
    
    arr[2] += arr[1] * arr[0];
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
    
    arr[1] = 3;
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
}
```

In this code, is it possible to have `arr[2]` to auto-change whenever `arr[0]` or `arr[1]` is changed? Or is there any other approach to achieve this feature?

Comment: No.  To do that, it requires you to use classes and property change listener.

Comment: If it's a field, you can have the updater call a method and add logic to recalculate `arr[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not provide any native mechanism to achieve this.

What you need to do is to implement the [Observer pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) but it will force you to change the whole code and the way you are running it.

If you're interested about existing frameworks and technologies in Java's world you can take a look at [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) but again - it's completely different approach to implement you're logic and it's not possible to implement it as one liner.

---

The only thing you could do would be to forget about arrays, use `List` instead, and provide your own implementation of the interface that would run some custom logic in the overridden `add(int index, E element)` method - but I'm not sure does it answer your question.